# How to expose an event in a c# class?

Tags: c#, events

I am building a simple class to hold related methods. Part of this code includes synchronising to a database. The built in `SyncOrchestrator` class includes a SessionProgress event handler which I can wire up an event to.

What I would like to do is instance my class and then hook up an some code to this event so that I can display a progress bar (ill be using BGWorker).

So, my question is probably c# 101, but how do I expose this event through my class the correct way so that I can wire it up?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

(I also suggest you read the [Events tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28VS.71%29.aspx).)

```
public class SyncOrchestrator
{
    // ...

    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> SessionProgress;

    protected virtual void OnSessionProgress(MyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Note the use of a temporary variable here to make the event raisin
        // thread-safe; may or may not be necessary in your case.
        var evt = this.SessionProgress;
        if (evt  != null)
            evt (this, e);
    }

    // ...
}
```

where the `MyEventArgs` type is derived from the `EventArgs` base type and contains your progress information.

You raise the event from within the class by calling `OnSessionProgress(...)`.

Register your event handler in any consumer class by doing:

```
// myMethodDelegate can just be the name of a method of appropiate signature,
// since C# 2.0 does auto-conversion to the delegate.
foo.SessionProgress += myMethodDelegate;
```

Similarly, use `-=` to unregister the event; often not explicitly required.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
public event EventHandlerDelegate EventName;
```

`EventHandlerDelegate` should obviously be the name of a delegate type that you expect people to provide to the event handler like so:

```
anObject.EventName += new EventHandlerDelegate(SomeMethod);
```

When calling the event, make sure you use this pattern:

```
var h = EventName;
if (h != null)
    h(...);
```

Otherwise you risk the event handler becoming `null` in between your test and actually calling the event.

Also, see the [official documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx).

Comment: I think the preferred way to do this now is with the generic: `public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> EventName`

Comment: So would I add a new property to my class of the correct event type?

Comment: Didn't mean to submit that comment! Had more to write :)

Comment: (ok so enter submits the comment - who knew!). Im not sure how I would trigger that event when the synchronise raises its sessionprogress event within my class. Sorry if in not making any sense.

Comment: @Jon B: Yes, it is, and that delegate type could certainly be used here.  I only meant to provide the basic information about declaring delegate types.  @Sergio: You don't need a property -- make sure you use the "event" keyword.  If you declare the event like I describe, the compiler will generate the required property and event accessors for you.

Comment: @Sergio: See the last block of code.  That's how you raise the event.  You treat the EventName "property" (actually a field, but that's hidden from you) as a delegate and call it directly.  This will call all of the registered event handlers, one after the other.